# Where to put LESS, SCSS and JS files in ASP.NET MVC 6 Web Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building a website with ASP.NET MVC 6 and i discover NPM, Bower & Gulp. I've understood the utility of each one.

I would like to know how to organize my "wwwroot" folder. I assuming that i need to have my final bundled and minified css & js files in the "wwwroot" folder.

But where do i put my LESS, SCSS and custom JS files ? in "wwwroot" folder too or in a folder in my solution ?

And if i want to use boostrap for example, but with LESS sources, where do i put them ?

Comment: I have custom bootstrap theme, i've just put it into `/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/mybootstraptheme.css`. Honestly, you should put it where you want, but if it's JS, CSS, LESS, SCSS files I'm pretty sure that they should be in the wwwroot folder. Just create a good structure that makes sense to you.  
E.g: `wwwroot/less` for LESS files, `wwwroot/css` for CSS files and so on

Answer (score 0):

I added same as per Cicero suggested above and formed the folders inside wwwroot as per requirement. For example- my custom files (js/css/less) files goes in separate folder under respective category. Later on, I wanted to add few files for bundling and minification, so added the reference of required files in bundleconfig.json